# How to resize vs-popup in the context of vuejs

Tags: vue.js, popup

Im using vs-popup in order to display the contents when ever the button is clicked, but the size of vs-popup is fixed, and my contents looks clumsy, so I want someone to tell me how I can change width of the popup as per my requirement.

```
<vs-button class="btn" @click=" showModal=true" color="#7367F0" > Click me</vs-button>
<vs-popup class="helundo" title="How will i resize popup" :active.sync="showModal">
<div class="vx-row">
  <div class="vx-col w-full md:w-1/2 mb-base">
     <p> I want this content in the left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vx-col w-full md:w-1/2 mb-base">
      <p> I want this content in the right</p>
  </div>
</div>
</vs-popup>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
<!-- what should I add in order to resize the popup -->
</style>
```

And the output I'm obtaining is sent below:

[image: Here is my Output]

I want the popup bigger and it should be flexible such that what ever content I add must fit accordingly.

Please do help me, as I am unable to change the width of the popup, what ever I do it is same, but if I add too many contents the width increases for a extend and it becomes scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer myself, i am posting so that it can help others. If you are using vuesax library you might find out **_fixesVuesax.scss**

so just place this code there:

```
.con-vs-popup {
  z-index: 53000;

  .vs-popup {
    width: 200px !important; //You can change the width according to your content
    height: auto;
  }
  .vs-popup--content {
    width: auto !important;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```